# return didn't return. Windows api

Tags: python, winapi, return

Here's my code. When I run it the return statement doesn't return anything. Anyone know why?

```
import win32api as win
import time
import sys
def mouse_path(run):
    path = []
    while time.clock() < run:
        cords = (win.GetCursorPos())
        time.sleep(.1)
        path.append(cords)
    return path

mouse_path(10)
```

Comment: 10. It's the last line in the code.

Comment: Does your while loop ever meet the condition you set?

Comment: yup. The code evaluates for 10 seconds and then stops and returns nothing.

Comment: There's nothing to return to. The script exits. You have to write the return value to stdout, e.g. `print(mouse_path(10))`.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't python supposed to return  a list?

Comment: Your function will return a list your just not doing anything with said list - have you tried what eryksun suggested

Comment: Why is the list not printed to the shell though? And when do these kinds of situations arise in general? And yes, print works.

Comment: So the list isn't printed to the she'll when you run    print (mouse_path (10))

Comment: If I print it then it works

Comment: The `return` statement returns a reference to the calling scope. In `print(mouse_path(10))`, the `mouse_path` function returns the list to the global script scope, where it's used as the argument to the `print` function. `print` gets the string representation of the list and writes it to stdout, which should be console or terminal output if stdout isn't redirected to a file or pipe.

Comment: Also, while extra parentheses can help clarify complex expressions, putting the entire right-hand side of an assignment statement in parentheses clarifies nothing. It's just visual clutter. Use `coords = win32api.GetCursorPos()`. Also, don't make a habit of coming up with your own abbreviated names for modules. It's `win32api` not `win`. Don't force the reader to memorize made-up names for well-known modules. However, in some cases the community already has common abbreviated names such as `np` for `numpy`. That's fine, since it's well known.

Comment: I added the parentheses because I wanted to iterate through a list of tuples later on. I'm still not really understanding what you are writing about the return statement and stdout and stuff. Anything that I should read that will elaborate on this concept?

Comment: Have you worked through the official tutorial?

Comment: I don't know what the official tutorial is.

Comment: Nvm  just found it

Comment: but also. From my shell:    print((win.GetCursorPos())). Output was  
(550, 273)

Comment: Yes that command will only print the current coordinates as it's only getting the coords once

Comment: `win32api.GetCursorPos()` already returns a tuple. `(win32api.GetCursorPos())` just adds pointless parentheses around the expression. The only time parentheses without the comma operator returns a tuple is the empty tuple `()`. Otherwise `(4)` is just `4`, while `(4,)` is a tuple that contains `4`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! Also what section of the official tutorial should I specifically read that relates to the original issue?

Comment: You should really start the tutorial at the beginning, but, since you asked, the section on [defining functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) starts with a function that prints a value and then introduces the `return` statement.

Comment: Asking which specific section of the tutorial to read to solve this problem really highlights the flaws in your approach. The suggestion is that you should gain a broader understanding of the language so that you can benefit in other situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are running this from a .py file and not in interactive mode.  Objects that come back from a `return` statement are not displayed except in interactive mode.  Try wrapping the returned values in a `print` statement.

```
import win32api as win
import time
import sys
def mouse_path(run):
    path = []
    while time.clock() < run:
        cords = (win.GetCursorPos())
        time.sleep(.1)
        path.append(cords)
    return path

print(mouse_path(10))
```

I ran it and this was printed to screen:

```
[(514, 469), (545, 474), (606, 465), (654, 444), (705, 430), (754, 425), (795, 423), 
 (825, 426), (821, 443), (794, 466), (774, 472), (733, 468), (679, 421), (622, 379), 
 (578, 330), (540, 305), (489, 277), (442, 284), (424, 310), (417, 323), (425, 346), 
 (460, 375), (512, 417), (563, 422), (610, 377), (677, 317), (733, 291), (787, 298), 
 (817, 328), (824, 368), (823, 401), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), 
 (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), 
 (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), 
 (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), 
 (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), 
 (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), 
 (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), 
 (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), 
 (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), (812, 419), 
 (812, 419)]
```

Comment: The repr of the return value is printed in interactive mode because of the default [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) function.